# Show jquery.colorpicker plugin dialog below clicked button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, color-picker

In a WordPress 4.3 project I have Fabric.js stage with jQuery.colorpicker plugin for selection of color or background color. I can open the dialog for color selection, but the problem is that it is opened not below the selection button, but way down at the bottom of the page. How can I get it to show up under the selection button instead?

My code:

```
    var backgroundColorPicker = jQuery('.backColor').colorpicker({
        parts:          'full',
        alpha:          true,
        showOn:         'click focus',
        colorFormat:    'RGBA',
    });

    ...
     jQuery('.openTextBackColorPicker').on('click tap', function(event){
                event.stopPropagation();
                alert( " ++ openTextBackColorPicker event::"+var_dump(event) )
                alert( " ++ openTextBackColorPicker backgroundColorPicker::"+var_dump(backgroundColorPicker) )
                alert( " ++1 openTextBackColorPicker backgroundColorPicker::"+var_dump(backgroundColorPicker.obj) )
                backgroundColorPicker.colorpicker('open');
                backgroundColorPicker.x= event.clientX;  // I trye to set coords by click events - but fail
                backgroundColorPicker.y= event.clientY;

                alert( "x::" + backgroundColorPicker.x + " y::" + backgroundColorPicker.x )

                alert( " ++22 openTextBackColorPicker backgroundColorPicker::"+var_dump(backgroundColorPicker) )
                ...
```

You can see live demo [here](http://displo.com/wp-content/plugins/woo-dysplo-import/edit_template.php?post_id=19#).

Please login under Faceboook page to acccess this page.
Click on "add String" button 1) and "add label..." 2) will be added at picture. Select it with mouse and several items will appear.
Click on "Text background" button 3) to show colorpicker dialog.

[image]

Comment: Please don’t force users to login via third party social media site in order to see your demo. Many of us don’t use Facebook. —Any chance you could put it up somewhere else? jsfiddle e.g.?